# Fastest way to detect if a string fits in a sequence of strings

Tags: c#, sequence

Imagine a sequence of strings like that:

- aa11
- aa12
- aa13
- .....
- aa99
- ab11
- ....
- az99
- ba11
- ....
- zz99

I want to detect if a `test` string exists in between a sequence of strings that is determined by `startString` and a `endString`. For example:

```
string test = "cc53";
string test2 = "hf15"

string startString = "aa11";
string endString = "ff99";

test.ExistsInBetween(startString, endString)   // must be true
test2.ExistsInBetween(startString, endString)  // must be false

public static bool ExistsInBetween(this string input, string start, string end)
{
    // I don't know where to begin
}
```

I already tried (successfully) generating all the strings between the start and end into a `HashSet<string>` and running a `hash.Contains(test)`, however as you can imagine this performs very poorly with longer strings.

Caveats:

1. The strings can be of different lengths (however, the three strings will always have the same length in a given test)
2. The characters can be only numbers or numbers and letters

Comment: @TimSchmelter no, I have only two strings that behaves like a sequence, and I need to test if this 'sequence' contains a third string

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry, was a mistake. fixed

Comment: To answer this one needs a clear definition of the sequence. Is it a simple standard sorting thing? Then simply compare your input with the start and endvalue.

Comment: For each individual position, you can check if the character lies between the start and end values. Anyhow, the description is incomplete. Should we assume ansi encoding? Utf8? Is '1' before 'a' or after? Is it case sensitive? Are there special characters?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it can start with any value, like '0000', 'aa00', 'aaaa' or 'aa11'. The start is determined dynamically by the startString

Comment: @JHBonarius assume only letters and numbers, i.e. a to z, and 0 to 9

Comment: `I already tried (successfully) generating all the strings between the start and end into a HashSet<string> and running a hash.Contains(test), however as you can imagine this performs very poorly with longer strings.` where is this code? Also in your code you did provide you have `// I don't know where to begin`, please tell us the real issue you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `string.Compare` should work:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ExistsInBetween(this string input, string start, string end)
    {
        return string.Compare(input, start) >= 0 && string.Compare(input, end) <= 0;
    }
}
```